# is animation allowed in an onClick() function

Tags: android

I tried using the following code in .java(main activity):

```
final ImageView diskView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.can);
diskView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){

        System.out.println("Clicked.");

    AnimationSet canMov;
        RotateAnimation canRotate;
    TranslateAnimation canTrans;

            canMov = new AnimationSet(true);
            canRotate = new RotateAnimation(0,1360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f );
            canRotate.setStartOffset(50);
            canRotate.setDuration(20000);
            canMov.addAnimation(canRotate);
            canTrans =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.35f);
            canTrans.setDuration(20000);
            canMov.addAnimation(canTrans);
            canMov.setRepeatCount(0);
            canMov.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            diskView1.setAnimation(canMov);
            }
  });
```

I am able to get the message 'clicked' in LogCat, but the animation after that does not respond to the click.
However, without the use of onClick(), I get the full animation of the can.
I need the animation to start only after I click the can.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an exception in the LogCat?

Comment: Debug: GC_EXPLICIT freed 91 objects. no exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling this in the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Where are you calling startAnimation(animatorSet) method?

Comment: Thanks.. But, it did not work.. Did not find any change in LogCat too.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem (working in a fragment). i created a method to animate an image view by sliding it out to the right. if i called the method in onCreateView for example, it would work.

i then attach a listener to an image view (with setOnClickListener) and call the animation method from with onClick. the animation does not work even though the animation method is called (as i can see on my log).

i found that if i called clearAnimation() for the image view to which the animation is attached then the animation would work.

so, if my image view that i want animated is called imageViewHouse, i would add this as the first line in my animation method: imageViewHouse.clearAnimation(). i then load the animation like this: pushRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.push_right); and start the animation with: houseView.setAnimation(pushRight);

it works for me, don't know why but it does (took me hours to find it out!). hopefully will help someone else.

regards

clive